# Write arbitrary html tag attribute based on *ngFor 'first' variable?

Tags: angular

I have a component which uses *ngFor to display a list of widgets/DIVs, each of which contains a textarea element.

I want to set the focus on the first textarea to appear from this list of widgets/DIVs.

Can I use the 'first' variable of the ngFor directive to write arbitrary html? In my case, I would like to add the 'autofocus' tag/attribute into the first textarea element my component writes:

e.g. `<textarea autofocus></textarea>`

I put a sample plunkr here that works, but it uses the ngAfterViewInit() method, which seems clunky to me when my component knows which element is first in the list:
https://embed.plnkr.co/a3zXZd9WBFNTj6yu1oU6/

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just bind `first` local variable to autofocus:

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of NAME_LIST; let first = first;">
  {{name}}<br />
  <textarea [autofocus]="first"></textarea> <br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid this, in part, because it either didn't make sense to me or seemed ugly and/or inexact.  but i tried it out and it seems to work, and now my question is why does it work?  the output seems to produce this DOM/html: `<textarea ng-reflect-autofocus="true" autofocus=""></textarea>` . the autofocus 'property' as seen thru chrome debugger is 'true' -- which is great -- but i think that means that the actual `autofocus=""` tag/text/attr-value-pair is ignored? and maybe it is the `ng-reflect-autofocus="true"` angular-generated attr-value pair that is working?

Comment: `autofocus=""` is not ignored. The value of `autofocus` attribute is not important: as long as attribute is present it translates into `autofocus` property equal `true`. That means that `autofocus=""`, `autofocus="autofocus"` or even without value `autofocus` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

you can use index variable :

```
<div *ngFor="let name of NAME_LIST; let i = index;">
  {{name}}<br />
  <textarea [autofocus]="i === 0"></textarea> <br /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setAttribute()** method as below,

HTML will be as

```
<div>
  <h2>How to set focus on first TEXTAREA element from list?</h2>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let name of NAME_LIST">
    {{name}}<br />{{first}}
    <textarea ></textarea><br /><br />
</div>
<span> {{getFocused()}} </span>
```

Typescript method:

```
getFocused(){
    document.querySelectorAll('textarea')[0].setAttribute("autofocus", "true");
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO UPDATED PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/75bA6oNBzTIXDn5xmtZp?p=preview)**